# Java programming- generics and jokers

Tags: java, generics

I'm a CS student learning to a Test in Software (introductory course in OOP and Java), and I didn't understand the Core difference between generic type (`<T>`) and Joker types (`<?>`). However, I did understand that the joker is more "inclusive".
can someone denote the differences, and similarities between those?
thanks!

for example, I know that the first method is compiled successfully, yet the second is not.

```
public <T> void f1(List<T> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

```
public void f2(List<?> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0));
}
```

Comment: `<?>` denotes that one does not know the generic type. This concept is known as wildcard. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one at `docs.oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Answer (score -1):

The generic type `T` serves as a *"special variable"* that stores a data type. During compilation, it is replaced with the specific type that it represents.

This offers flexibility when creating new objects.

For instance, instead of having `IntegerArrayList` or `StringArrayList`, we can utilize a single class with a custom data type (which is translated at compile time), such as `new ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<String>`. These are identical classes, only differing in the data type they store.

The wildcard (`?`) operates in a similar way, but in contrast to the generic type `T`, it requires knowledge about the superclass.

With a wildcard, there are two possibilities:

1. Using `List<? extends MyClass>`, we can ensure that each object in the list is of type `MyClass`.
2. On the other hand, with `List<? super MyClass>`, we can guarantee that the list is capable of containing `MyClass` type, but the objects cannot be directly instances of `MyClass`.

I hope this helps clarify things.

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java)))

Comment: The reason you are getting downvoted is because your answer strongly implies reification, which is exactly what Java generics ***DO NOT DO***. Maybe you meant something else?